Your new site design is live!
As you can see, the new design just went live!
At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with design and bug). Thank you for your valuable design feedback and for your patience while we got this design out for you.
We really hope you like the design! Thanks so much to scoso for his work on this!

Love it.  Very classy!

I love it!  Thank you so much.

The header looks great but I personally find the contrast of the orange (or gold) to white a bit harsh/straining on the eye (preferred the blue).

Thank you V2Blast for the design of the site! Can I check if there are any posts/work on a dark mode for the quant finance stack exchange?

@KaiSqDist: Well, I got laid off from Stack in October, so I couldn't tell you if there have been any updates – but generally, dark mode being implemented on the SE network would probably be something announced on MSE first.

Oh shucks, sorry to hear that. I am sure someone as capable as you will find another great opportunity soon.
